# DNS problems on pool of preemptible-only nodes on GKE: endpoints of kube-dns service keeps failed pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, dnsmasq

I do have a GKE k8s cluster (k8s 1.22) that consists of preemptible nodes *only*, which includes critical services like kube-dns. It's a dev machine which can tolerate some broken minutes a day. Every time a node gets shut down which hosts a kube-dns pod, I run into DNS resolution problems that persist until I delete the failed pod (in 1.21, pods stay "Status: Failed" / "Reason: Shutdown" until manually deleted).

While I do expect some problems on preemptible nodes while they are being recycled, I would expect this to self-repair after some minutes. The underlying reason for the persistent problems seems to be that the failed pod does not get removed from the k8s `Service` / `Endpoint`. This is what I can see in the system:

Status of the pods via `kubectl -n kube-system get po -l k8s-app=kube-dns`

```
NAME                        READY   STATUS       RESTARTS   AGE
kube-dns-697dc8fc8b-47rxd   4/4     Terminated   0          43h
kube-dns-697dc8fc8b-mkfrp   4/4     Running      0          78m
kube-dns-697dc8fc8b-zfvn8   4/4     Running      0          19h
```

IP of the failed pod is 192.168.144.2 - and it still is listed as one of the endpoints of the service:

`kubectl -n kube-system describe ep kube-dns` brings this:

```
Name:         kube-dns
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=Reconcile
              k8s-app=kube-dns
              kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true
              kubernetes.io/name=KubeDNS
Annotations:  endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time: 2022-02-21T10:15:54Z
Subsets:
  Addresses:          192.168.144.2,192.168.144.7,192.168.146.29
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name     Port  Protocol
    ----     ----  --------
    dns-tcp  53    TCP
    dns      53    UDP

Events:  <none>
```

I know others worked around these issues by [Scheduling kube-dns to other pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934637/scheduling-kube-dns-on-dedicated-node-pool), but I would rather want to make this self-healing instead, as node failures can still happen on non-preemptible nodes, they are just less likely.

My questions:

- Why is the failed pod still listed as one of the endpoints of the service, even hours after the initial node failure?
- What can I do to mitigate the problem (besides adding some non-ephemeral nodes)?

It seems that kube-dns in the default deployment in GKE does not have a readiness probe attached to dnsmasq (port 53), which is targeted in the kube-dns service, and that having that could solve the issue - but I suspect it's not there for a reason that I don't yet understand.

EDIT: Apparently this does *not* happen on 1.21.6-gke.1500 (regular channel), but it does on 1.22.6-gke.1500 (rapid channel). I do not have a good explanation, but despite having a few failed pods today the kube-dns service only contains the working ones.

Comment: Update: Looks like a k8s bug that will be fixed in 1.22 later on: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/108594 - I will update with an answer to my own question once I have verified this working. Florian, if you can read this, if you make your now-deleted comment an answer to this post I can accept it as an answer later on and you get the credit.

Answer (score 2):

Preemptible nodes are not recommended for running critical workloads such as kube-dns ([1](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/preemptible-vms#best_practices)) so situations like this are to be expected.

You can try mitigating the issue by marking pod as critical ([2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/guaranteed-scheduling-critical-addon-pods/#marking-pod-as-critical)), using node auto-provisioning ([3](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning)) or PodDisruptionBudget ([4](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-to-set-pdbs-to-enable-ca-to-move-kube-system-pods)).
There are more information on this topic in this doc ([5](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/best-practices-for-running-cost-effective-kubernetes-applications-on-gke#introduction)).

Additionally, some suggestions have been already made to Google ([6](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/139735350)).

If none of these resolve your problem you can report this via
[Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: Correct, adding a node pool with standard nodes will make this less likely - but those nodes can still fail, and I do not see how this cannot happen in the same way e.g. when an availability zone fails. That is the main reason why I asked initially. Human intervention would be necessary for that case as well, correct?

Comment: I never witnessed such situation and did not found any reports of such behavior in the issue tracker. But if you encounter this problem on a non-preemptible node then this should be reported to Google.

Answer (score 0):

It started happening on my env(preemptible nodes on gke) as well and it happens to all deployments, but kube-dns is the most critical one. I think it might be related to `revisionHistoryLimit` parameter. The default value is 10, so old replicas up to a count of 10 will be present for some period of time. I've set it to 0 and expect nodes to be replaced, let's see :)